# Run javascript autoscroll function after page full load

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, pageload, autoscroll

I have a functionality on a page that should auto-scroll by javascript when a url matches:

```
$(window).load(function () {
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("something-on-url") > -1) {
                $("html,body").animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#specificDiv").offset().top
                }, 300);
        }
```

The problem is that I have a carousel of images at the top of the page, and it takes a while until its loaded, so it makes the autoscroll before the carousel is there (the carousel height is not taken into count so it's autoscrolling as many pixels as it should minus the carousel height).

I've tried `document.ready()` instead of `$(window).load`, same result. I've tried adding the picture/carousel height, but if I go `img.height()`, it will give me "0" at that time, and hardcoded it it's not an option since this is a mobile responsive site. I've also tried using `.onload()` to the img tag in the carousel and on the carousel tags, but this just doesn't trigger the autoscroll (never).

Only thing working so far, it's delay the scroll function with a `setTimeOut()`, but depending on the user it may load the carousel slower, so a safe `setTimeOut()` will be to long for most cases.

Comment: is there a "ready" or load complete for your carousel object? ideally you would get a call back from the API that is setting up the carousel object so you could then call the scroll when that completes. What carousel are you using?

Comment: Can you explicitly give the carousel a height so that even though it's not loaded at runtime, it at least has some physical dimensions that can be used in the auto scroll?

Comment: workabyte: orbit
trnelson: can't, since responsive design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix by looking into the carousel documentation thanks to the comment of the user workabyte. This is how it looks now:

```
  $(window).load(function () {
            if (window.location.href.indexOf("something-on-url") > -1) {
                $(".orbit-slides-container").one("orbit:before-slide-change", function () {
                    $("html,body").animate({
                        scrollTop: $("#specificDiv").offset().top
                    }, 200);
                });
            }
```

The `orbit:before-slide-change` is a event from the orbit API (http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/components/orbit.html). There is also an event supposedly triggered when the carousel is fully loaded, `orbit:ready`, but this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the `onload` event is not called when the image is already cached.

To make it work you need to check `this.complete` and `this.readyState` as well.

You could use something like this:

```
$.fn.whenLoaded = function(fn){
    return this.each(function(){
        if (this.complete || this.readyState == 'complete') {
            fn.call(this);
        } else {
            $(this).load(fn);
        }
    });
}

$('img#firstCarouselImage').whenLoaded(function(){
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("something-on-url") > -1) {
         $("html,body").animate({
            scrollTop: $("#specificDiv").offset().top
         }, 300);
    }
});
```

Comment: didn't work, it does scroll down, but still before the carousel loads :(